# How to Post the value to Drupal Custom table using REST API in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, drupal-views

We have created the custom module to post the value to the drupal custom table using REST API.

We get the below error.

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.InvalidArgumentException: Field name is unknown. in Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase->getTranslatedField() (line 587 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase.php).

Comment: It will not work if your are using entity save for storing value in custom table. Use INSERT query to store the data.

Comment: thanks for the answer. do you have any other options?